# Scapy Error --> IndexError: Layer [None] not found

Tags: scapy

I am trying to build a NIDS using scapy to capture real time packets. The error *Layer [None] not found* keep appearing even though I added the checking of IP and TCP layers.

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.inet import IP, TCP

features_list = []


def packet_handler(packet):
    print(packet.summary())

    if packet.haslayer(IP) and packet.haslayer(TCP):
        dur = packet.time
        proto = packet.proto
        service = packet[TCP].sport
        state = packet[TCP].flags
        spkts = len(packet[TCP].payload)
        dpkts = 0 if packet[TCP].payload == b"" else 1
        sbytes = len(packet[TCP].payload)
        dbytes = 0 if packet[TCP].payload == b"" else len(packet[TCP].payload)

        rate = spkts / dur

        sttl = packet[IP].ttl
        dttl = packet[IP].ttl

        sload = sbytes / dur

        dload = dbytes / dur

        sloss = 0 if spkts == 0 else (spkts - dpkts) / spkts

        dloss = 0 if dpkts == 0 else (dpkts - spkts) / dpkts

        sinpkt = 0 if spkts <= 1 else dur / (spkts - 1)

        dinpkt = 0 if dpkts <= 1 else dur / (dpkts - 1)

        if spkts <= 1:
            sjit = 0
        else:
            sjit = sum(abs(packet[IP].time - prev_packet[IP].time) for prev_packet in packet[IP].payload[:-1]) / (
                    spkts - 1)

        if dpkts <= 1:
            djit = 0
        else:
            djit = sum(abs(packet[IP].time - prev_packet[IP].time) for prev_packet in packet[IP].payload[:-1]) / (
                    dpkts - 1)

        swin = packet[TCP].window
        stcpb = packet[TCP].seq
        dtcpb = packet[TCP].ack
        dwin = packet[TCP].window

        # Handle the case where TCP layer is missing or fields are not set
        tcprtt = 0 if packet.haslayer(TCP) and packet[TCP].ack is not None and packet[
            TCP].seq is not None and packet.sent_time is not None else 0
        synack = 1 if packet.haslayer(TCP) and packet[TCP].flags.S and packet[TCP].flags.A else 0
        ackdat = 1 if packet.haslayer(TCP) and packet[TCP].flags.A and packet[TCP].flags.P else 0
        smean = len(packet[TCP].payload) if packet.haslayer(Raw) else 0

interface = 'Wi-Fi'

print(f"Starting packet capture on interface {interface}...")
sniff(iface=interface, prn=packet_handler, store=0)
```

This is the output with the error:

```
Starting packet capture on interface Wi-Fi...
Ether / IP / TCP 45.113.128.33:https > 192.168.0.11:55635 PA / Raw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\carlson\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\StepbyStep\2.1 Features Extraction.py", line 104, in <module>
    sniff(iface=interface, prn=packet_handler, store=0)
  File "C:\Users\carlson\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 1311, in sniff
    sniffer._run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\carlson\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 1254, in _run
    session.on_packet_received(p)
  File "C:\Users\carlson\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\scapy\sessions.py", line 109, in on_packet_received
    result = self.prn(pkt)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\carlson\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\StepbyStep\2.1 Features Extraction.py", line 52, in packet_handler
    sjit = sum(abs(packet[IP].time - prev_packet[IP].time) for prev_packet in packet[IP].payload[:-1]) / (
                                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\carlson\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 1327, in __getitem__
    raise IndexError("Layer [%s] not found" % name)
IndexError: Layer [None] not found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I apologize if the title of this question is wrong or the problem is too simple to solve, This is my first time asking on Stack Overflow and I am a beginner in using Scapy.

I tried adding the checking
packet.haslayer(IP) and packet.haslayer(TCP):
and
if IP in packet and TCP in packet:

but both did not work